# Laravel livewire script full path

Tags: laravel-livewire

If i have a laravel project in

```
c:\xampp\htdoc\proj -> http://localhost/proj
```

and public url

```
c:\xampp\htdoc\projpubl -> http://localhost/projpubl
```

Using the laravel livewire, the javascript url is

```
<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=83b555bb..." data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>
```

I want to do the url like:

```
<script src="http://localhost/projpubl/livewire/livewire.js?id=83..
```

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you host your application in a path which is not the root in your domain, you need to publish the Livewire configuration and set the `asset_base_url` property. This is stated in [the documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installatiom).

To publish the config-file, run

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

You will get a copy of the Livewire-config file in your project, located at `config/livewire.php`.

Find the `asset_url` property (aprox. line 57) and set it to

```
'asset_url' => '/projpubl'
```

Just to note, since I don't know how you've set your project up, anything outside the `public` directory in Laravel should never be accessible from any HTTP request.